# How can i implement ROR testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

Can you one please guide.... i want to implement Testing in  my Rails application.... i never do that before.... so i don't know how to implement testing. can any one please tell me is their any link should follow for step by step process ... please.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Ryan has some excellent railscasts about testing:

- http://railscasts.com/tags/7

I recommend you start there.  He has a very easy to follow style, and is a great teacher for new users and old users alike.

Answer (score 1):

You could also take a look at RailsGuides' guide on testing in Rails:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

and various testing framework options here:

http://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/testing_frameworks.html